# Worried about html/script injection in angular app

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, code-injection

I am working on an angular app that has a textarea. The contents of this textarea are then used to populate a preview of the entered text. All of this is done on the client. I am worried that someone will be able to inject code into my app e.g.

```
<html>
    <script>/*Some script here*/</script>
</html
```

I have pretty much no experience with code injection. Is this a legitimate concern? If anyone needs more information to assess this risk please do not hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to prevent XSS attacks when using Angular. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: If you're just using `ng-bind` or `{{}}` bindings html entities are encoded automatically.  If you want to use `ng-bind-html` or actually display HTML you may want to use `$sanitize`

Answer (score 5):

Use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize), just inject the module in the app and you are "safe"

Comment: "safe"? I'm guessing I can never be safe?

Comment: no sorry for double quotes, with that in place you are completely safe from injection like those you talked about